# Trying to merge 4 table cell of 3*3 image grid in react native

Tags: react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQFVj.png)

I want to merge 2,3,5,6 image in to one image so that my view looks like instagram explore tab's view

now I am having no ideas how to build this view

Can you guys suggest any ideas or keyword for me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know flexbox (which is how I'm assuming you made your 9-box version), this image should be helpful: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xtOe.jpg

Boxes of the same color are siblings, and are weighted either `flex: 1` or `flex: 2` based on their weight in the layout. Also, the containers are either `flexDirection: 'column'` or `flexDirection: 'row'` based on the layout needs of their direct children:

```
<View style={{width: '100%', height: 300, flexDirection: 'column'}}>
  <View style={{flex: 2, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column'}}>
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red', margin: 2}} />
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red', margin: 2}} />
    </View>
    <View style={{flex: 2, backgroundColor: 'red', margin: 2}} />
  </View>
  <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red', margin: 2}} />
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red', margin: 2}} />
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red', margin: 2}} />
  </View>
</View>
```